# How to make the last footer fixed (ListView)

Tags: android, listview, footer

I have a `ListView` with 2 footer views. The first one is a bunch of `TextView`s, while the second one is a button. I'm trying to fix the second footer so that it always shows at the bottom of the screen.

I tried the following:

```
1.  alignParentBottom = true

2.  layout_gravity="bottom"

3.  footerView2.bringToFront()
```

And combinations of the above. But none of them worked out. How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I shouldn't have added the `View` which I always want on the screen (fixed) as footer.

I just added the wannabe-fixed-view with the listView. Did `alignParentBottom = true` and also `view.bringToFront()`. It worked out for me.

Comment: This second footer will be visible and fixed when whole of the listview will be scrolled , right ?

Comment: Yeah, when the whole listview is scrolled, the first footer is scrolled... The second footer will always be visible and fixed at the bottom.

Comment: add `layout_weight="1"` in listview.

Comment: Can you show your listviews xml

Comment: Don't use a footer if you want it to have a permanent, fixed location. Add another `View` below your `ListView` as part of your layout file.

Comment: @user5038993 was about to right the same as PPasrtisan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your `ListView` and bottom footer. The idea is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Bottom button"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/btn_bottom"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: yup, that was what I was missing. Clear point. I also had to use `bringToFront`.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate xml file which contain all textviews and button you want as footer part.Then bind this xml as a footer of listview. You can binf footer with listview by this method:   `listview.addFooterView(footerView);`
For example:

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.listviewfooter, null, false);
        spDate = (Spinner) headerView.findViewById(R.id.spdate);
        llDatepicker = (LinearLayout) headerView.findViewById(R.id.lldatepicker);
        rvDatepicker = (RecyclerView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.rvdatepicker);
        rvTimepicker = (RecyclerView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.rvtimepicker);

              lvAddress.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you are Trying to add a View which will be shown even if we scroll the List Up or Down... u can do something like this. I had done this before But as a header.

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/new_container"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LOAD EARLIER MESSAGES"
        android:id="@+id/loadMore"
        android:background="#90F58220"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listContainer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/loadMore"
        android:layout_above="@+id/container">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/messagesContainer"
            android:transcriptMode="normal"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:stackFromBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

       </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </RelativeLayout>

The LoadMore Button is always visible on the Top of the List...
To add it to footer, Just Change

    android:layout_below="@+id/loadMore"
    android:layout_above="@+id/container"

to

    android:layout_above="@+id/loadMore"
```